# C# equivalent of python itertools.izip_longest

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to figure out if there is built-in support to zip two IEnumerables of different lengths without losing the elements from larger list in C#.

Essentially I'm looking for Python (>= 2.6) version of `izip_longest` from `itertools` in C#.

I'm also open to other nifty custom solutions using `LINQ` to get the same functionality. To illustrate more,

if `a = [1, 2, 3]` and `b = [4, 5, 6, 7]` the desired output should be `[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6], [7]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote an own zip extension method that walks over the `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T[]> Zip<T>(this IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
{
    IEnumerator<T> leftEnumerator = left.GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<T> rightEnumerator = right.GetEnumerator();

    bool hasLeft = leftEnumerator.MoveNext();
    bool hasRight = rightEnumerator.MoveNext();

    while (hasLeft || hasRight)
    {
        if (hasLeft && hasRight)
        {
            yield return new T[] { leftEnumerator.Current, rightEnumerator.Current };
        }
        else if (hasLeft)
        {
            yield return new T[] { leftEnumerator.Current };
        }
        else if (hasRight)
        {
            yield return new T[] { rightEnumerator.Current };
        }

        hasLeft = leftEnumerator.MoveNext();
        hasRight = rightEnumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] b = new int[] { 4, 5, 6, 7 };

IEnumerable<int[]> zipped = a.Zip(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

LINQ itself has a [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) method with combines elements from two sequences and applies a function to them (which can simply combine the elements to a pair). The result is as long as the shortest sequence though.

The MoreLINQ library adds several extensions to LINQ including methods like     `MaxBy`, `ExceptBy` and various [strategies for Zip](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Zip.cs?r=03799046f7e508c90c3733212bf6da57e55191ad), including return shortest (Zip), longest (ZipLongest) or fail on mismatch (EquiZip).

The example from the docs shows that ZipLongest will return the default value for missing elements:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
string[] letters = { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
var zipped = numbers.ZipLongest(letters, (n, l) => n + l);
/// ... will yield "1A", "2B", "3C", "0D" in turn.
```

You can download the code or binary packages for individual operators (eg for [ZipLongest](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MoreLinq.Source.MoreEnumerable.ZipLongest/)) from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=morelinq), or you can download the [binary package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/1.2.0) for the entire library.